# Do shell functions in bash executed in shell context or fork-n-exec fashion?

Tags: bash

In bash commands are executed in fork-and-exec fashion.
Similarly a new process is forked (subshell) to execute script file.
I am curious how shell functions are interpreted and executed?
Do commands listed in shell function too work in fork-and-exec fashion or they are executed in current shell context.

Comment: If you are on Linux then you can investigate using `strace`, looking for calls to `vfork`.

Comment: You can also look at the `bash` source code:   `execute_cmd.c`, specifically `execute_function` within that file.

Answer (score 1):

Since `BASHPID` expands to the *PID* of the current process, you can check it by yourself:

```
#!/bin/bash

function print_pid() {
    echo $BASHPID
}

echo $BASHPID
print_pid
```

both *PID*s displayed are the same. So, no `fork` takes place. Functions are executed in the current shell process.

Comment: You have to be careful of `$$`.  Bash fakes the `$$` in some subshell scenarios.  Form the `bash` `man` pages:  *BASHPID
              Expands  to  the  process  ID of the current bash process.  This
              differs from $$ under certain circumstances, such  as  subshells
              that do not require bash to be re-initialized.*

Answer (score 1):

Functions run in the current shell process. Note that they can modify the shell's variables.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, functions run inside the current shell environment. However, note that anything invoked via command or process substitution, including a function, runs in a separate environment (subshell or new process, depending on what it is). So if you do something like `output=$(some_shell_func)`, then the function can have no side effects in the parent shell.